# Add indexed sheets to Excel workbook w/out Openpyxl?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

Working with Python 2.7 and I'd like to add new sheets to a current Excel workbook indexed to a specific position. I know Openpyxl's `create_sheet` command will allow me to specify an index for a new sheet within an existing workbook, but there's a catch: Openpyxl will delete charts from an existing Excel workbook if opened & saved. And my workbook has charts that I don't wish to be deleted.

Is there another way I can open this workbook, create a a few blank sheets that are located precisely after the existing first sheet, all without deleting any of the workbook's charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openpyxl 2.5 includes read support for charts

Comment: I tried downloading and installing openpyxl 2.5 but it's still deleting the charts

Comment: Then please submit a bug report with a sample file and detailed description, thanks.